# ASPOSE: How to correctly get Total Rows in Worksheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, aspose-cells

Currently using Aspose for .NET in a C# WebService.
I am currently having issues getting the correct Total Rows using worksheet.Cells.Rows.Count
It is showing that I have around 230 rows but inside the file, I only have 14 rows.
I am guessing because I reuse my Excel file and deleted some rows by highlighting the rows then pressing the delete key.

When I recreate a brand new Excel file, then copy-paste the 14 values in the new file. The worksheet.Cells.Rows.Count works correctly.

Would this be a bug in the library or am I deleting the values in Excel file wrongly or I am using a wrong count property?

Am I missing something?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, RowCollection/ColumnCollection.Count attribute would give you total number of rows/columns which are initialized, so it won't be always reliable to get total number of data rows/cols. I think you should use Worksheet.Cells.MaxDataRow and Worksheet.Cells.MaxDataColumn properties to get the farthest (last) row/column indices (0 - based), see the sample code segment for your reference:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook("Book1.xlsx");
     //Get the farthest (last) row's index (zero-based) which contains data.
     int lastRowIndex = workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells.MaxDataRow;

     //Get the farthest (last) column's index (zero-based) which contains data.
     int lastColIndex = workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells.MaxDataColumn;
......
```

Hope, this helps a bit.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks Amjad! That worked for me! I did a workaround before your answer which was to check the first null/whitespace that I encountered, then break the looping of rows. But your solution is a much better way.Glad to know that it is easy to reach an Aspose expert here. Cheers!

Comment: @amjad-sahi I believe you have an error in your lastRowIndex = line, as Cells() is invalid, but Cells works (and would match the lastColIndex = line).

Comment: @DJFriar you are spot on, I have corrected the typo/mistake in the sample code of the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I used this but get wrong column count:

```
var dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(0, 0,worksheet.Cells.Rows.Count, worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count, options);
```

Instead of worksheet.Cells.Rows.Count and worksheet.Cells.Rows.Count use these : **worksheet.Cells.MaxRow + 1** and **worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn + 1**

This works correctly :

```
var dataTable = worksheet.Cells.ExportDataTable(0, 0, worksheet.Cells.MaxRow + 1, worksheet.Cells.MaxColumn + 1, options);
```